# PHP - Switch on a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, switch-statement, case

I try to do a switch on a multidimensional array :

```
$types = array (
'type1' => array('value1', 'value2'),
'type2' => array('value3', 'value4');
...
);

$prefix = substr($number, 0, 4);

foreach ($types as $key => $values) {
    switch ($prefix) {
        case 'type1' :
            $type = 'TYPE1';
            break;
        case 'type2' :
            $type = 'TYPE2';
            break;
        ...
      }
}
```

Where the $prefix is equal to a value in $types array.

But it didn't works. I guess i'm close to the solution, but can't find it (googled gave me nothing more). Thanks (:

Comment: `$prefix` -> `$key` maybe? Just maybe...

Comment: What is `$prefix`? You mean `$key`?

Comment: Edited : Where the $prefix is equal to a value in $types array;
@Rizier123 : Didn't works. It returns me the last case before default, which is incorrect.

Comment: Is `$prefix` an array? If yes you never loop through it!

Comment: Edited again... x)
$prefix is a string who contains 4 numbers, extracted from a string, previously.

Comment: is $prefix = 'value1' or 'value2' or 'value3'...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand.
If `$prefix` = `'value1'` or `'value2'` or `'value3'` .... you can try something like this:

```
foreach ($types as $key => $values) {
    if (in_array($prefix, $values) )
        $type = strtoupper($key);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. :) Thank's for the return. The next time, be more explicit. ;)

Comment: yey, my first post ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have no `$prefix` in this code.
Try this:

```
$types = array (
    'type1' => array('value1', 'value2'),
    'type2' => array('value3', 'value4')
);


foreach ($types as $key => $values) {
    switch ($key) { // $prefix does not exist (at least not according to this code).
        case 'type1' :
            $type = 'TYPE1';
            break;
        case 'type2' :
            $type = 'TYPE2';
            break;
      }

}
```

Comment: Edited : $prefix is a string who contains 4 numbers, previously extracted from a string.

Comment: Then you need to explain better what you want to do, because its hard to know what you want to compare $prefix to. Do you want to compare it to the $key ("type1") or any of the values in $values (array("value1","value")) of $types?